# Java generics: how to get a generic class's Id in a generic interface?

Tags: java, generics

I am using JDK 7.

I have an abstract class **`BaseEntity`** which is using generics:

```
public class BaseEntity<Id extends java.io.Serializable> {
  protected Id id;

  public BaseEntity() {
  }

  public Id getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Id id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  // also has hashCode() and equals() methods to be based on id
}
```

Now I want to create an interface whose type would be **`BaseEntity`** and I also want the **`Id`** of **`BaseEntity`** to be available in the interface. How can I do that?

I tried this code:

```
public interface BaseLookup<T extends BaseEntity> {
   T findById(Id id);
}
```

but I got 2 messages:

1. 1st one was on **`BaseEntity`**. The message was:

> Base Entity is a raw type. References to generic type `BaseEntity<Id>`
>   should be parameterized.

2. 2nd one was on `"Id"`. The error message was:

> Id cannot be resolved to a type.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface BaseLookup<Id, T extends BaseEntity<Id>> {
   T findById(Id id);
}
```

Since you parameterized `BaseEntity`, you should *always* use a parameter whenever you reference `BaseEntity`. That first warning you got was telling you that you were using the `BaseEntity` (with no parameters) raw type, which is something that really only exists for legacy code and shouldn't be used. Since, ostensibly, `BaseEntity` is not just one type but an entire collection of types (one for each `T`), we need to tell it *which* `BaseEntity` we're extending, which amounts to adding an additional generic argument.

Comment: your answer is giving me error message on 2nd Id. The error is **Bound mismatch: The type Id is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Id extends Serializable> of the type BaseEntity<id>**

Comment: `<Id extends Serializable, T extends BaseEntity<Id>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type of `BaseEntity` in `BaseLookup`. For better readability, I defind `ID` type as `I`.
You could use something like this:

```
class BaseEntity<I extends java.io.Serializable> {
      protected I id;

      public BaseEntity() {
      }

      public I getId() {
        return id;
      }
      public void setId(I id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      // also has hashCode() and equals() methods to be based on id
}

interface BaseLookup<I extends java.io.Serializable, T extends BaseEntity<I>> {
      T findById(I id);
}
```